# HTML form in php foreach loop table not getting output

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a Html form in the PHP for loop. The for loop is fetching the data from a database and putting it in a table. Each row has a button which says SUBMIT.What I want is that,when I click on submit buttom a html form will appear with the unique number of that particular row. So, the problem is when I click on the very first row Submit button the form appear's up. But when I click on the other row's Submit button the form doesn't show's up. I don't know why.

My php code with form:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="active1">ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Critility</th>
    <th>Priority</th>
    <th>Date Submitted</th>
    <th>Submittions</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<?php foreach($results as $data){
  echo '<tbody>
    <div class="tryinglift"><tr class="dropDown">
      <td><div class="bn">#'.$data['NO'].'</div></td>
      <td><div class="titleInTable truncatee">'.$data['Title'].'<div></td>
      <td><div class="truncate">'.$data['Description'].'</div></td>
      <td><div class="c">'.$data['criticality'].'</div></td>
      <td><div class="c">'.$data['Priority'].'</div></td>
      <td>'.$data['Date_Submitted'].'</td>
      <td><button id="showPop" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">SUBMIT</button></td>
    </tr></div>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="specialBox">
      <form action="php/inbetween.php" method="POST" class="submittion_from">
        <fieldset class="removeGender1">
          <label>NO</label>
          <label >YES</label>
        </fieldset><br>
        <input type="text" name="id" value='.$data['no'].'>
        <fieldset class="removeGender">
          <label>xyz questions</label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="NO">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio" value="YES">
        </fieldset><br>
        <fieldset class="removeGender">
          <label>xyz questuion</label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="NO">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio1" value="YES">
        </fieldset><br>
        <fieldset class="removeGender">
          <label>xyz questions</label>
          <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="NO">
          <input type="radio" name="optradio2" value="YES">
        </fieldset><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="no">
      </form>
      <button id="closePop">Close Overlay</button>
    </div>
  </tbody>';
  echo '<div id="style1"> <div>'.$data['Description'].'</div> </div>';
} ?>
```

My jQuery for the web form:

```
    $("#showPop").click(function(){
    $("#overlay").css({"display":"block"});
    $("#specialBox").css({"display":"block"}); 
});
$("#closePop").click(function(){
   $("#overlay").css({"display":"none"});
    $("#specialBox").css({"display":"none"}); 
});
```

Sample image When I click on the first row submit button :[image]

Comment: Is there anything in your browser's console?

Comment: No, there is nothing in the browser console

Comment: You've got duplicate IDs. Every ID needs to have a unique. Instead use classes.

Comment: I tried using classes, still the same, but when i change id with class the only difference is that when i click on the first row submit button the unique number in the form is of the last row. rest everything is the same

Comment: You definitely need to use classes since duplicate IDs is invalid HTML. The problem is that your code is not specifying which instance of `#overlay` to show. So switch that to a class rather than an ID and then use `$(".overlay").closest().show();` so it knows which one to show.

Comment: *"when i click on the first row submit button the unique number in the form is of the last row"* - I'm guessing that's because ALL of your `.specialBox` divs are showing and the last one has the highest z-index. I would suggest you just have one single `.specialBox` div and populate the form values with the `onclick` event.

Comment: can you show me how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: Add a `data` attribute to each button containing the unique identifier of that row from the database (e.g. `data-id="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"`) and in your `.click()` method, you can access that value with `$(this).attr('data-id')`.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying me back, I have understand the code above but I am struggling on how to implement it?